# Google Sheets - Iterate through text string, removing charters from end until a vlookup match

Tags: google-sheets

A user pastes in a value to see if there is a full or partial match. I need to do a `vlookup` and keep removing characters until there is a match. A full match of something like `test1.test2.test3` is no problem because it's a full match to my list. But if someone pastes in something like `test1.test2.test3.test4`, I need to remove a character one at a time from the end until there is a match. So in this example, it would match `test1.test2.test3` and return that result.

Conceptually I see this as a `for` loop that counts the characters using `len`, using `left` to remove the number of characters from the end based on the current iteration, and doing `vlookups` until returning the value when true. But I'm not sure how to do this in Google Sheets.

Comment: Did you consider REGEXMATCH? It can do the job by looking for any matching strings in array to a value you supply in a cell...

Answer (score 0):

This formula will give you the matching value that was found in the data
(i.e. `test1.test2.test3`)

```
=FILTER([column_with_data], REGEXMATCH([cell_with_pasted_value_to_look], [column_with_data]))
```

This formula will give you the matching data and the cell reference where it was found
 (i.e. `test1.test2.test3 @ $A$4`)

```
=FILTER([column_with_data], REGEXMATCH([cell_with_pasted_value_to_look], [column_with_data]))&" @ "&CELL("address",INDEX([column_with_data],MATCH(FILTER([column_with_data], REGEXMATCH([cell_with_pasted_value_to_look], [column_with_data])),[column_with_data],0),1))
```

Simply copy & paste any of the above formulas next to the cell where users paste a value to look. Then, replace the two references in the square brackets `[ ]` with the proper coordinates in your sheet:

1. replace `[column_with_data]` with the coordinates of the column containing all the stored data (i.e. `A1:A`)
2. replace `[cell_with_pasted_value_to_look]` with the absolute (`$col$row`)coordinates of the cell where users paste the value to look (i.e. `$B$1`)

Answer (score 0):

Would it be a problem to download the data from Google sheets, transform the file type to use the for loop in another software, and re-upload? I think your idea for a for loop would work.

It might be quicker if this is a long term project, but not so great if the client is continually monitoring/uploading.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).